# What is the difference between @Published and normal AnyPublisher property in ObservableObject

Tags: swiftui, combine

I consider what is the difference

```
@Published var isLoggedIn: Bool = false 

var isLoggedIn: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never>
```

I know in the case of first I can use it directly in SwiftUI View i.e. create binding with $ sign and then for example use `if $isLoggedIn.animation()`

But how can I achieve the same with `AnyPublisher<Bool, Never>` it seems that there I need to call somewhere **assign** or **sink** and **store()**. To make it work. So creating binding from it in SwiftUI seems to be impossible like `if $isLoggedIn.animation`

Limitation of @Published is that I cannot make there custom observing. for example UserDefaults which I can do via AnyPublisher from UserDefaults.publisher.

As now it seems I need to have both and make `AnyPublisher` update `@Published var`

But I've thought that @Published is property wrapper that has underneath regular AnyPublisher so why I cannot make binding in SwiftUI view directly from AnyPublisher?

Comment: "... of @Published is that I cannot make there custom observing." Why not? It has publisher like any other subjects, you can use operators, sink ... whatever you need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Combine's `@Published` is a publisher that's wrapped by a property wrapper. This gives it the `$` prefixed property and other features that SwiftUI relies on to work.

An `@Published` property is also not like an `AnyPublisher` at all. `@Published` always has `Never` as its failure type, `AnyPublisher` can have other failure cases.

`@Published` has a sense of state/ a current value which isn't the case for `AnyPublisher`. A `CurrentValueSubject` would come closest but that wouldn't work because `@Published` can be used as a binding which isn't possible for `CurrentValueSubject`. An important difference is that SwiftUI can assign new values to an `@Published` property directly (`isLoggedIn = true` would trigger a change here).

To work with your publishers in SwiftUI you'll need to assign their values to a dedicated `@Published` property as you mentioned in your original question.

Comment: You seem to mix SwiftUI with Combine. `@Published` isn't a SwiftUI-specific property wrapper, it's not even part of the framework.

Comment: Whoops, you're right. Easy to mix the two up. Apart from the first word in my answer the rest of it is accurate though. I'll update that so the answer is correct.

Comment: @donnywals I am new to Combine and struggling to understand how to assign the value to the dedicated Published property.  Can you some example code that would show how to do this?  I am specifically trying to use combineLatest() to combine two Published values into a new Published value.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

example usage of custom observing

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var flag = false
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: Model
    let handle: AnyCancellable?
    init() {
        let m = Model()
        handle = m.$flag.sink(receiveValue: { (b) in
            print("model flag changed to:", b)
        })
        model = m
    }
    var body: some View {
        Toggle(isOn: $model.flag) {
            Text("Toggle")
        }.padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

from SwiftUI.View the publisher is accessible as

```
$model.$flag
```

if needed.